# Create Sliders for Folium Maps to dynamically update the map as the user moves the sliders

Tags: python, pandas, gis, folium, folium-plugins

I am trying to create a folium choropleth with Python and add sliders that correspond to a weighting factor. As the user moves the slider the weighting is changed and the column df[col] is calculated. I have written the code below but I have two issues:

1. Everytime I press update map a new map is created in my VS Code
2. Moving the sliders does not change the df[col] below is my code
3. My users dont have VS Code or a notebook i want the output to be in .html so users on their own can toggle with the sliders and get a new map

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider, Button
from IPython.display import display

# Define the factor names and columns

factor_names = factor_columns
factor_columns = factor_columns  # Replace with actual column names

# Initialize the global weights and total weight
global_weights = [0, 0, 0, 0]
total_weight = 0.0

# Select the first dataframe
df = condensed_df_dict['condense_merge_df_LastYear']

# Set the CRS
df.crs = "EPSG:4326"

# Create the folium map
m = folium.Map(location=[df['geometry'].centroid.y.mean(), df['geometry'].centroid.x.mean()], zoom_start=10)

# Function to calculate the RISK and update the map
def calculate_electrification_risk():
    global total_weight
    total_weight = sum(global_weights)
    for df_name, df in condensed_df_dict.items():
        df['RISK'] = 0
        for weight, column in zip(global_weights, factor_columns):
            df['RISK'] += weight * df[column]
        df['RISK'] = df['RISK'] / total_weight
        df['RISK'] = df['RISK'].fillna(0).astype(int)
        bins = [0, 3, 7, 10]  # define the range of each bin
        labels = ['Low risk', 'Medium risk', 'High risk']  # define the labels of each bin
        df['risk_category'] = pd.cut(df['RISK'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

# Function to update the map with the current data
def update_map(_):
    global choropleth
    for key in choropleth._children:
        if key.startswith('color_map'):
            del choropleth._children[key]

    for i, factor_name in enumerate(factor_names):
        global_weights[i] = slider_controls[i].value 
    calculate_electrification_risk()
    # Remove the existing choropleth layer
    choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=df,
        name='RISK',
        data=df,
        columns=['SA2_MAIN16', 'RISK'],
        key_on="feature.properties.SA2_MAIN16",
        fill_color='RdYlBu_r',
        fill_opacity=0.6,
        line_opacity=0.3,
        legend_name='RISK',
        #show=True
    )

    tooltip = GeoJsonTooltip(
    fields=['SA2_NAME16', 'ID_COUNT', 'Decile ranking of the SA2 within Australia', '% Rented', 'high_rise_cnt',
            'high_rise_pct', df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('zero')][0], df.columns[(df.columns.str.contains('less_than_'))&(~df.columns.str.contains('_ decile'))][0],
            'RISK', 'risk_category'],
    aliases=['Suburb Name: ', 'ID Count: ', 'Socio Economic Decile: ', '% Rented:', 'High rise Count:',
             '% Highrise: ', '% 0 GJ Usage Customers: ', f'% Less than {usageList[1]} GJ customers: ', 
             'RISK Decile: ', 'Risk Definition:'
             ],
    localize=True,
    sticky=False,
    labels=True,
    style="""
        background-color: #F0EFEF;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 3px;
    """,
    max_width=800,
    ) 
    choropleth.geojson.add_child(tooltip)
    choropleth.add_to(m)  # Add the updated choropleth layer to the map
    display(m)
    print(global_weights)
    print(total_weight)

    m.add_child(folium.map.LayerControl())

# Function to handle button click event
def button_click(_):
    update_map(None)  # Call the update_map function to update the map

# Create the update button
update_button = Button(description='Update Map')
update_button.on_click(button_click)
slider_controls = []
for factor_name in factor_names:
    slider_control = FloatSlider(
        min=0,
        max=100,
        value=0,
        step=1,
        description=factor_name,
        continuous_update=False,
        orientation='horizontal', 
        layout={'width': '1500px'}, 
        style={'description_width': '350px'}  
    )
    slider_controls.append(slider_control)
# Display the sliders and update button
for slider in slider_controls:
    display(slider)
display(update_button)

# Display the initial map
display(m)

total_weight 
global_weights
```

Comment: Since folium itself has the ability to dynamically color-code the map by moving the slider, it is easy to use that function. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/TimeSliderChoropleth.ipynb). You can also see the results [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/TimeSliderChoropleth.ipynb).